# Error on installing a package "n low severity vulnerabilities"

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-ios

I just installed a fresh react-native project on big-sur.

When i try to install a npm package, i got this error.

How can i fix it?

```
npm install @react-navigation/native


up to date, audited 1026 packages in 2s

6 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

When execute the "npm audit fix --force" command, the app is not  working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not an error, everything works fine...